# Retrieve selector content in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to fetch one table from DOM and print it to the shell.

```
this.waitForSelector("table[bgcolor|='#ffffff']",function(){                
    casper.echo(document.querySelector("table[bgcolor|='#ffffff']"));
});
```

But it keeps printing `null`.

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading javascript variable from website using PhantomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831098/reading-javascript-variable-from-website-using-phantomjs)

Comment: The other good read is this: [null for elements in phantomjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808221/null-for-elements-in-phantomjs)